# Boot off of USB drive problem - new iMac

Tags: macos, imac, usb, startup, downgrade

how can i boot off of usb disk to install snow leopard onto new iMac that has mavericks installed

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as your iMac won't let you boot into an OS X version that's older than what it shipped with. Snow Leopard does not have the necessary drivers for the new iMac.